# Rotating up and down along whole screen attempts to go 360, but limited to 180

Tags: javascript, three.js

In OrbitControls.js
There is a function:
function handleMouseMoveRotate( event ) {

```
    //console.log( 'handleMouseMoveRotate' );

    rotateEnd.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );
    rotateDelta.subVectors( rotateEnd, rotateStart );

    var element = scope.domElement === document ? scope.domElement.body : scope.domElement;

    // rotating across whole screen goes 360 degrees around
    rotateLeft( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.x / element.clientWidth * scope.rotateSpeed );

    // rotating up and down along whole screen attempts to go 360, but limited to 180
    rotateUp( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.y / element.clientHeight * scope.rotateSpeed );

    rotateStart.copy( rotateEnd );

    scope.update();

}
```

So when I want to rotate up and down , it only allows to rotate angels between 0 and 180, how can I get rid of this limitation? That means, I want to rotate up and down any angel without 0 to 180 limitation.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Is it (0, 180) or (-180, 180)?

Comment: It is (0, 180) .

Comment: Use `TrackballControls`, instead.

Comment: Thanks WestLangley, it worked now by using TrackballControls.